# How to use the output clang++ -fsave-optimization-record command?

Tags: clang++

I compiled with the `clang++ -fsave-optimization-record` command.

Now I have a `file.opt.yaml` file but I don't know what to do with this file...

Is there a tool to visualize something or to display its content ?

I wonder the same thing for `clang++ -fdiagnostics-show-hotness`.

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

The official tool to handle these yamls is called `opt-viewer` and was developed by Adam Nemet from Apple. It is thinly documented [here](https://llvm.org/docs/Remarks.html#opt-viewer) but the best intro to it is still [this 2016 talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qq0q1hfzidg). `fdiagnostics-show-hotness` is used to enrich the same yamls with PGO data.

It is a suite of python scripts, processing the generated `yaml`s into htmls of the compiled sources with the optimization remarks as inline annotations:
[image]

The optimization remarks themselves are essentially internal logs of various optimization passes (not all), which typically carry meaning only to pass maintainers.

My personal experience with the tool left me wanting more, and so I set out to improve it and came up with OptView2. It is available [here](https://github.com/OfekShilon/optview2) and described [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qmEsx4MbKoc). For one, the documentation is more than 3 lines and the intro talk describes common optimization-remarks and what can be done about them. If you do choose to use it - I'd appreciate any feedback.